# How to most efficiently use Pandas UDF in Spark with multiple Series as inputs

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have some PySpark code that aims to run a machine learning model trained in sklearn on a pyspark dataframe looks like this:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
X = np.random.rand(1000, 100)
y = np.random.randint(2, size=1000)
tree = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=4)
tree.fit(X, y)
pdf = pd.DataFrame(X)
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

@pandas_udf('double')
# Input/output are both a pandas.Series of doubles
def pandas_plus_one(*args):
    return pd.Series(tree.predict(pd.concat([args[i] for i in range(100)],axis=1)))

df = df.withColumn('result', pandas_plus_one(*[df[i] for i in range(100)]))
```

My question is that is this the most efficient way to do things with PySpark? In particular, I would like to avoid having to do pd.concat which involves copying all the Series (which were probably adjacent in memory anyways) to a new pandas DataFrame inside of the UDF function. The ideal solution would be for the Pandas UDF to accept a DataFrame as an input, but I haven't found a way to make it work.

**Note: I am not looking for solutions that involve SparkML scikit-spark etc.**